# How to use ECMAScript 6 in webextensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use ECMAScript 6 in my webextension in Chrome 51 (in my background.js code) but I get an error on the first import: "Unexpected token import". I enabled experimental javascript features in Chrome. Is there any information available anywhere about using ECMAScript6 in webextensions?

Comment: That's interesting. ES6 is available everywhere in Firefox. Can you paste your code. It may be that part of ES6 isn't supported yet.

Comment: It just fails on the first 'import' statement at the top of background.js, I therefore don't think it has anything to do with the rest of the code? I already rewrote it in ES5 anyway so it's gone, but it was just a couple of files with classes. I tried it in Chrome 51 on Mac, not in FF that won't even load the extension

Answer (score 1):

Firefox supports [most parts of ES6](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), but [not modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility). It's being worked on under [bug 568953](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=568953).

Comment: Thanks but I was using Chrome 51. I removed the firefox-webextensions tag for clarity, why this tag is firefox specific I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Native support for ES6 modules is quite a thing. A common way to go is to have a build that bundles modules. [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) is commonly used for that.

I just created a [skeleton](https://github.com/simomat/firefox-addon-skeleton) for webExt add-ons that does this.